# How to get single Tap confirmed event in onTouch()?

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

Actually I wanna get `singleTapConfirmed()` event inside onTouch method . As we all know we can use `gestureDetector` class for that purpose but I wonder how to do that with `onTouch`

And I don't wanna call `GestureDetector#onTouchEvent` I wanna detect that manually.

Below code is there for double tap from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15946976/8027365) but how to get singleTapConfirmed in this code

Code for DoubleTap:

```
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
           @Override
           public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
               switch(event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK)
               {
                   case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                       startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                       clickCount++;
                       break;
                   case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                       long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
                       duration=  duration + time;
                       if(clickCount == 2)
                       {
                           if(duration<= MAX_DURATION)
                           {
                               Toast.makeText(imageView.getContext(), "double tap",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                           }
                           clickCount = 0;
                           duration = 0;
                           break;
                       }
               }
               return true;
           }
       });
```

Comment: simply call `GestureDetector#onTouchEvent` inside `onTouch` method

Comment: @pskink no sir I wanna detect that manually

Comment: manually? what do you mean? do you think that `GestureDetector` checks single tap "not manually"? what do you want to achieve actually? check for a single click or what?

Comment: @pskink sir please check my edited question as we can detect double tap in onTouch how to do that with singleTapConfirmed . Manually means I wanna increase the singleTapConfirmed method's time duration

Comment: see `GestureDetector` source file and check `DOUBLE_TAP_TIMEOUT` and `DOUBLE_TAP_MIN_TIME`

Answer (score 1):

It will be fine to use gesture detection with onTouch listener as below

```
final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
     //do something
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        super.onLongPress(e);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        return super.onDoubleTap(e);
    }
});
```

and use gestureDetector as

```
 viewToTouch.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
});
```

Comment: sir could you please help me to increase the singleTapConfirmed() event's time duration . I need to increase it's time duration because I wanna use both singleTapConfirmed and doubleTap but in some cases singleTapConfirmed is called first

Comment: what is meant by increase the singleTapConfirmed()

Comment: I meant the time duration of singleTapConfirmed() event

Comment: @user8027365 so did you check DOUBLE_TAP_TIMEOUT and DOUBLE_TAP_MIN_TIME or not? have you seen `GestureDetector` source code?

Comment: @pskink yes I did [from this link](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/GestureDetector.java) but I'm confused how to customize that . Could you please spare some of your time to customize that it would be a great help for me

Comment: @user8027365 just set the values you want (they are in milliseconds) lines 227 - 228

Comment: @pskink but sir I'm unable to use that class . It's showing not found method error for a lot of methods

Comment: @user8027365 so get the sources from android froyo (API level 8) or even eclair (API level 5)

Comment: @pskink where to get them could you provide any link

Comment: @user8027365 from the same link but not using **master** branch

Comment: @pskink sir it's working but only one method **getDoubleTapSlop()** is not found . Is there any alternative to this method

Comment: @user8027365 and you cannot fix it? you really cannot find that method in `ViewConfiguration`?

Comment: @pskink sorry sir  I hadn't copied that by the way great thanks for your time and enlightenment

Comment: @user8027365 you hadn't copied what?

Comment: `ViewConfiguration`

Comment: @user8027365 you dont have to copy that file, just see how **getDoubleTapSlop** is implemented (but of course you can copy it if you really want)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

           startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                   clickCount++;

        }
    });
```

OnTouchListner  return falsh so detact touch event

```
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
       @Override
       public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
           switch(event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK)
           {

               case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                   long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
                   duration=  duration + time;
                   if(clickCount == 2)
                   {
                       if(duration<= MAX_DURATION)
                       {
                           Toast.makeText(imageView.getContext(), "double 
                           tap",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                       }
                       clickCount = 0;
                       duration = 0;
                       break;
                   }
           }
           return false;
       }
   });
```

Comment: No sir it's not allowing the doubleTap event to happen . Only singleTap event is happening

Comment: @pskink sir I'm just a beginner in that could you please help me to do that

Comment: @user8027365 make return false in on TouchListner